# Applying different equations to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a task using pandas and I'm wondering if the code can be optimized. The code pretty much goes as:

All the dataframes are 919 * 919. `socio` is a dataframe with many fields. `matrices` is a dictionary that holds different dataframes objects.

I apply a series of formulas and store the results in the `result` dataframe.

```
import numpy as np

frame = [zone for zone in range(taz_start_id, taz_end_id +1)]    
#frame = list from 1 to 919

result = DataFrame(0.0, index=frame, columns=frame)

#Get a seires type and apply the results to all the rows of the dataframe by index
temp = np.log(socio["ser_emp"] + 1) * 0.36310718
result = result.apply(lambda x:  x + temp[x.index], axis = 0)

#Divide two columns apply a coefficient and fill all the nan to 0. apply results to result dataframe 
temp = (socio["hhpop"] / socio["acres"]) * -0.07379568
temp = temp.fillna(0)
result = result.apply(lambda x:  x + temp[x.index], axis = 0)    


result = (matrices['avgtt'].transpose() * -0.05689183) + result    

# set a 1.5 value if dist is between values or 0 if not
result =((matrices["dist"] > 1) & (matrices["dist"] <= 2.5))  * 1.5 + result

# see if each cell is 0 if not set value to exp(value)
result = result.applymap(lambda x: 0 if x == 0 else exp(x))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use an awkward `lambda` to do the addition.  You can use the `add` method with a parameter `axis=0` that specifies which axis to match the lower dimensional argument.

I bundled the two `Series` you are adding into one so you only have to broadcast across the index once.

Next, I just changed to match my style and improve my readability

Finally, the finding where not zero and filling in with `exp`, I'm assuming `exp` is numpy's `exp` via some import `from numpy import exp` or something.  Otherwise, replace with `np.exp`.  This is much more vectorized.  `result` is a dataframe and `mask` makes anything that evaluates to `True` from the passed condition statement into `np.nan`. I then chain a `fillna` with a vectorized call to `np.exp(result)`

```
result = result.add(
    np.log(socio.ser_emp.add(1)).mul(.36310718).add(
        socio.hhpop.div(socio.acres).mul(-.07379568).fillna(0)
    ), axis=0)

avgtt, dist = matrices['avgtt'], matrices['dist']
result += avgtt.T * -0.05689183 + ((dist > 1) & (dist <= 2.5)) * 1.5

result = result.mask(result != 0).fillna(exp(result))
```

Comment: This is pretty helpful! ill go ahead and approach it the way you are. Thank you. Ill wait to see if there are other answers before accepting your answer.

Comment: trying `result = result.add(np.log(socio.basic_emp + 1).mul(0.24160834))` is returning the dataframe with all 0 and not with the updated value, any idea why?

Comment: you don't have `axis=0`

Comment: you are right thanks. this seems to be working now